# PHP - Validating decimals using NumberFormatter

Tags: php

The application that I'm working on accepts decimal numbers from users in non-English locales, mostly Danish.

The code for validating the numbers looks like this:

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter($locale, NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$amount = $fmt->parse($input);
if ($amount === false) {
    echo "There has been an error with the number {$input}";
}
```

This works fine in that it throws errors for strings and accepts decimals. My problem with NumberFormatter is that for example "12,34,,,,5,34" is accepted and formatted to 12.34

Now, "12,34,,,,5,34" is not a decimal number, it should be rejected. I tried combining this with `is_numeric()`, but `is_numeric()` rejects both ""12,34,,,,5,34" and 12,34.

My question is, is there a way to make NumberFormatter reject "12,34,,,,5,34" as this is not numeric??

Comment: You could use NumberFormatter::PATTERN_DECIMAL and provide your own validation

Comment: Makes sense if only I get to understand why and how can 12,34,,,,5,34 be accepted as decimal

Comment: It can't, if you consider the whole string.. but the NumberFormatter isn't intended to validate an input either, therefore it parses a string until it encounters an invalid character. Just like PHP would do..

Answer (score 1):

The `NumberFormatter` is not intended to be used as input validation. You could try the [`filter_var`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.filter-var)/[`filter_input`](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.filter-input) methods instead:

```php
<?php

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE');

$options = [
    'options' => [
        'decimal' => \localeconv()['decimal_point'],
    ],
];

$input = '10,0205,,04';
var_dump(
    filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT, $options)
);
# bool(false)

$input = '10,0205';
var_dump(
    filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT, $options)
);
# float(10.0205)
```

Hope I could help

/Flo

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)
I like the approach, and I think this method in general can work. The problem here though is that all float numbers with commas give false for some weird reason